# keybinding for macOS Sierra

Tags: keybindings

As it needs 3 keys on a German keyboard (alt shift 7) to get a backslash, I would like to use the keys on the numerical keyboard to get this character (and others difficult to obtain as é).  I tried two different versions of ~/Library/Keybindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
available at
http://alexanderstoffel.selfip.org/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding1.dict
and
http://alexanderstoffel.selfip.org/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding2.dict
After rebooting, the first version has the effect that hitting the corresponding keys does neither insert the former nor the desired character but the acoustic system alert is audible. The second version does not have any effect. How can I get the desired effect?  I am using a MacBook Air with macOS Sierra (10.12.1) and with an additional Apple Keyboard (Product-ID: 0x0250).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had much luck the keybinding dict route, seems very spotty what works and what doesn't. Far easier to use an app like Ukulele to make a tweaked keyboard layout exactly how you want it - no issues whatsoever. Much recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to Ukelele. After getting acquainted to the quite complex program, I could solve the problem. It seems still a little clumsy to me to establish a whole keyboard layout file just to change about 10 keys, but anyway, the practical problem is solved. If someone finds out the mistake in the keybinding files, I would still be interested in.